# Linker error with extern "C++" function call: Uncommon usage

Tags: c++, c, linker-errors, new-operator, extern

I would like to demonstrate a small sample of my project where I receive Linker error accessing a function defined with extern "C++". What would be the best way to access this function given that my project allows both C and C++ linkages?

/// Filename: new

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <exception>

extern "C++" {
namespace std
{
  typedef void (*new_handler)();
  new_handler set_my_handler(new_handler) throw();
}
```

/// Filename: main.c

```
extern void handler();

void main() 
{
  handler(); 
}
```

/// Filename: App.cpp

```
#include <new>

static App objApp;
void no_memory()
{
  // exit
}

void App::init()
{
  using namespace std;
  set_my_handler(no_memory);
} 

extern "C" void handler()
{
  objApp.init();
}
```

*I get the following linker error:*

> ../../obj/output/stm32-debug/Project/App.o: In function `App::init()': undefined reference to set_my_handler(void (*)())'

Earlier "set_my_handler" was defined to be extern "C" in the library, but now its extern "C++". I have not seen much usage of extern "C++" which restricts calls from C++ linkages alone. But in my project I have a C function that eventually accesses the C++ function described under extern "C++". Curious on why the linker cries as in above.

> Observation: If I do not call objApp.init() [i.e. comment this line out] I do not
>   get any linker error. The issue pertains with call flow from C towards
>   C++ function marked extern "C++".

Comment: I think the person downvoting did not go through my question before downvoting. This is not a duplicate question. It is a question pertaining to extern "C++" function access and not the same question. Request you to kindly revert the downvote.

Comment: There is a clear demarcation between extern "C" and extern "C++". The latter is not a common usage and the question highlights the latter. I believe one would agree.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question since there is a difference between extern C and extern C++.

Comment: @hago I am pretty sure that the primary dupe covers that.

Comment: Correction: Removed the duplicate extern. My bad, was a typo. The linker error is still relevant.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ , I read the primary dupe. Eventhough it is tagged for C++, there is no example for extern "C++" which is the question by this OP.
So, I believe that, this question is relevant and not a duplicate.

Comment: @hago It's still about symbol mangling mismatch anyhow. No matter of direction coming  from `extern "C++"` or `extern "C"`.

Comment: Even if the question is reoppened, it'll probably be closed again for lack of a [mcve].

Comment: You put the function into namespace `std` (which is UB but it probably doesn't cause the linker error.) So it needs to be referenced as `std::set_my_handler`. But don't do that. Put it into your own namespace. (And what do you think `extern "C++"` buys you?)

Comment: Thanks @rici appreciate someone at least addressed an attempt to answer the question than unnecessary debate on dupes. The <new> file is a file from stlport library and it has extern "C++" in its new version. I cannot change that. In the earlier version, it was extern "C". My question has remained on making this link with extern "C++" usage. I don't see many using extern "C++" and is also hardly googleable. Thanks.

Comment: Also to add, if I do not call objApp.init() I do not get the Linker error (Question/observation appended).

Comment: @sammy: That's probably dead code elimination. Anyway, since you don't show anywhere where `std::set_my_handler` is actually defined (and not just declared), there's no obvious reason to believe that the linker is mistaken. (In other words, I can't find that function either.) A [mcve] might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I am trying to find the "definition" of set_my_handler in code. It could be that internally it is disabled and we can only see the declaration. I get the linker error "only" when the caller calls the function objApp.init() (inside which the set_my_handler is called). This is when the linker will link the symbols and not otherwise.  Upvoted your answer. @rici